# Dojo - Stores vs Individual Service components

Tags: dojo

Dojo proposes to use Stores for managing Data on client side. As far as I know Stores should be used when we have a collection of data. Should we use stores if some service returns only one object and not a collection of data?

Comment: You could if you want, but stores are usualy used for binding backend data to a widget, if you only have 1 value and it does not change, then it seems like too much overhead

Comment: Is it architecturally correct to use it? I can always create service utility component which will handle the server interaction for that particular value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: You can use stores for collection or even only for one object.

`dojo/store` propose a uniform interface for the access and manipulation of stored data.

In my experience, generally you could use `dojo/store` when you need to build more complex components (example a grid which get and push data to an API) .

In case you have just a simple widget, adding a store increase complexity and perhaps it is not necessary.

Dojo store have several ¨modules¨ for more complex operations, here a brief overview:

`dojo/store/Memory`:
If you need to queries, modifies, and accesses more complex client-side in-memory data

`dojo/store/JsonRest`:
If you need to queries, modifies, and accesses data through RESTful HTTP requests.

`dojo/store/Observable`:
If you need data monitoring capability. Observing changes in object properties and so on.

`dojo/store/Cache`: 
If you need caching capability to your store.